# Why is Stable Diffusion + Roop API Call throws httpException?

Tags: python, json, rest, stable-diffusion

I tried to build an API call to a Runpod instance of Stable Diffusion with Roop Extension. The Webui working correctly, now i build a serverless endpoint based on [this worker](https://github.com/generativelabs/serverless-pod-a1111). There i can inference correctly without roop. Now i try to build a call with roop arguments like in this [example](https://github.com/s0md3v/sd-webui-roop/blob/e3bbbd1c150d30e6184314b45a37dde2797bbd19/example/api_example.py) from roop's git site.
Here is my relevant code:

```
image_file = "./example.png"
im = Image.open(image_file)

img_bytes = io.BytesIO()
im.save(img_bytes, format='PNG') 
img_base64 = base64.b64encode(img_bytes.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')

# roop arguments list
args=[
    img_base64, # image input
    True, # enable
    '0', # comma seperated face numbers
    '/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/models/roop/inswapper_128.onnx', # model
    'CodeFormer', # restore faces 
    1, # restore visibility
    True, # restore face, upscaler
    None, # upscaler
    1, # upscaler scale 
    1, # upscaler visibility
    False, # swap in source image
    True, # swap in generated image
]

# create payload
payload = json.dumps({
  "input": {
    "api_name": "txt2img",
    "prompt": prompt,
    "restore_faces": True,
    "negative_prompt": negPrompt,
    "seed": -1,
    "override_settings": {
        "sd_model_checkpoint": "dreamshaper_7.safetensors [ed989d673d]",
    },
    # "model" : "SDv1.5",
    "sampler_index": "DPM++ SDE Karras",
    "cfg_scale": 5,
    #"sampler_index": "DDIM",
    "sampling_method" : "euler a",
    "sampling_steps" : 20,
    "num_inference_steps": 30,
    "width" : 576,
    "height" : 960,
    "alwayson_scripts": {"roop": {"args":args}},
  }
})
```

After that i get a response:
`{'delayTime': 14042, 'error': 'HTTPException', 'executionTime': 1637, 'id': 'e6f166af-575c-4670-8850-64563e639762', 'status': 'FAILED'}`

Why is the minimal example failing?

Answer (score 2):

request POST:- `yourserverUrl:port/roop/image`

```
const body = {
  "source_image": "",
  "target_image": "",
  "face_index": [
    0
  ],
  "scale": 1,
  "upscale_visibility": 1,
  "face_restorer": "None",
  "restorer_visibility": 1,
  "model": "inswapper_128.onnx"
}
```

if you want to get your available models then hit this as GET request `yourserverUrl:port/roop/models`

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Below argument list works for me:

```
roop_args = [
roop_encoded_image,
True,
'0',
r'C:\myDir\Stable-Diffusion\stable-diffusion- 
webui\models\roop\inswapper_128.onnx',
'CodeFormer',
1,
None,
1,
'None',
False,
True
]
```